# USB Root Hub power surge with weird SSD behavior

Tags: usb, ssd, power

My new laptop seems to be having USB issues. It keeps telling me that there was a "Power surge on hub port" and that a device has "exceeded the power limits of its hub port." Also weird is that in Device Manager, it says my USB root hub has 13 ports on it- my entire laptop only has 2 physical ports though... Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: What OS and make/model of laptop?  Was your C drive always listed in your list of devices that can be "Safely Removed", or is that new behavior?

Comment: Dell Latitude E7440. I just got the laptop today, and it was always like that.

Comment: Is it truly a new laptop, or used? From whom did you purchase it?

Comment: It is a company laptop. It has probably had users before me.

Comment: My friend said that it sounded like the manufacturer had hooked the SSD up internally via USB 3.0 rather than SATA, which would explain both the performance decrease and the USB hub power surge since DevMan says the hub is only rated for 500 mA. What do you guys think? Would an OEM really be that stupid?

Comment: If your hard drive has always shown on the Safely Remove list, I wouldn't be concerned about it nor assume being on that list is related to the problem you're having.  Any device that reports itself to the OS as being hot-swappable will show on this list, which can include internal drives (see http://www.overclock.net/t/974023/fix-ahci-sata-drives-showing-in-safely-remove-hardware).  There are no internal USB ports on that laptop so that's not how your HDD is connected.  (Further, USB 3.0 is _almost_ as fast as SATA 6 Gbps).  Perhaps you have a Hybrid SSD drive, NOT a true SSD?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I found out that the SSD performance hit is because of BitLocker encryption on the hard drive. However, I'm still getting USB power surges, even when nothing is plugged in to any ports. And the root hub still reports 11 ports that don't physically exist on my machine. (I edited my question to remove the extraneous info about the SSD)